# In c# when using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject into a class, how to convert a decimal to a string within a subclass?

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

Modified post to simplify problem:

I have a json object that has the below structure. (data is faked)

I am attempting to deserialize this object using the common Newtonsoft JsonConvert functionality into a class named "Work"

var jWork = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Work>(strResponse);

My issue is that if I define the Work class to have public fields as strings, the DeserializeObject will correctly convert the Json values as strings.  In other words I can correctly convert the "StringDate" Json field when I have a class defined like below.

However if I define the subfields as classes themselves, the deserialize object no longer works and I get a conversion error.
In other words when I try to do public string DateValue {get ; set} inside of the "Person" class it throw a conversion error.

Why is this?

```
    public partial class Work
    {
        
        public Issues Issues { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Issues
    {
      
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Fields Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Fields
    {
    
        public string StringDate { get; set; } 
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public object Customfield11600 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Person
    {
    
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Income { get; set; }

/* I don't want this to be a DateTimeOffset?, i want it to read in the value as string, but if you put string here deserialize throws a conversaion error*/
        public DateTimeOffset? Datevalue { get; set; }

/*above works, this doesn't*/

        ***public string Datevalue { get; set; }***


    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is true?

```
{
      "issues"  : {
            "id": "test",
            "fields": {
                "StringDate": "2020-02-02",
                "person" : {
                   "name" : "baby",
                   "Income" : "50000.22",
                   "datevalue" : "2020-02-02"
                           },

                "customfield_11600": null
            }
  
                    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to work? The values are strings in JSON, so why would mapping them to objects be either what you wanted to do or what the library would do out of the box.

Comment: What do you mean you 'can't define a class that has the fields that are strings,' your example does exactly that? I guess what I'm saying is 'why are you trying to map a string value to an object type'. Best practice is to deserialize into a model that exactly matches the JSON schema, then transform that in code to whatever internal representation you want.

Comment: I updated my original question to hopefully better answer your question.  But my issue is: Say your json had a sub-json value of person, which itself had two fields...  How would i pull the income out of that sub-object (now in the above example) without defining a class named Person who had a public string income  field?

Comment: Got it. You shouldn't, because that's hiding business logic (mapping this external model to a less nested model), with serialization.

Comment: Apologize i'm very new to this, but what od you mean by that? If I was given the requirement to pull the income out of the person field in the above Json, and Also to pull the duedate out of it, and to keep them ALL as strings, how would i write the class to make this function?